# Python: Copy files with specific extension in a tree of directory

Tags: python

I need to copy files with extension of .jpg from a folder tree.
The folder tree is like this:

```
-folder_A
    -folder_1
        -1.txt
        -1.jpg
    -folder_2
        -2.txt
        -2.jpg
    -folder_3
        -3.txt
        -4.jpg
-folder_B
```

How can I copy all the `x.jpg` to `folder_B`?
i.e. All the files are the same in `folder_A`, and in `folder_B`, files are `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`...

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the python [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module.

```
import os
import shutil as sh

root_path = "./folder_A"
dest_path = "./folder_B"

for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(root_path):    
    for f in fnames:
        if f.endswith(".jpg"):
            source_file_path =  os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            dest_file_path   =  os.path.join(dest_path, f)
            sh.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you know your OS you can just execute the according shell-command.
(But I think the solution of @stellasia is cleaner)

Example (Linux):

```
import os

os.system('cp -r folder_A/*/*.jpg folder_B/')
```

Comment: It's better to give another example under windows system as well, to generalize your answer

Comment: I would like to give it, but I can not test it (because I do not have a windows here) But perhaps it is : 'copy etc…'