# Copying files with specified extensions with preserving a folder tree structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I've written (with huge help of internet) a script that is aimed to copy files with specified extensions from destiantion folder (and all subfolders) to new folder.

I've done it partially, but I have a problem.

My script is copying files as it is aimed to do, but simply paste them to the folder given as destination, without preserving folder tree structure.

My function doing this:

```
def copy_files_spec_ext(ext, file_path, root_path, dest_path):
ext_counter=0
ext="."+ext;
for root_path, dnames, fnames in os.walk(root_path):    
    for crt_file in fnames:
        if crt_file.endswith(ext):
            source_file_path =  os.path.join(root_path, crt_file)
            dest_file_path   =  os.path.join(dest_path, crt_file)
            shutil.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
            ext_counter=ext_counter+1;
return ext_counter;
```

The code is a modification of what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273924/python-copy-files-with-specific-extension-in-a-tree-of-directory#30274973)

I'am pretty new in python (a couple of months non intensive coding), so please have mercy ;-).
Thanks in advance for help.

PS. Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've read this code again, and apparently I've found what I am doing wrong.
I make another variable, that stores the difference between the source path that was given to the function and the tath in which the file was found, and the add this difference to the destination path.

Now the code looks like:

```
def copy_files_spec_ext(ext, file_path, root_path, dest_path):
ext_counter=0
ext="."+ext;
static_root_path=root_path;
for root_path, dnames, fnames in os.walk(root_path):    
    for crt_file in fnames:
        if crt_file.endswith(ext):
            source_file_path =  os.path.join(root_path, crt_file)
            additional_folders=os.path.relpath(root_path, static_root_path);
            dest_file_path   =  os.path.join(dest_path, additional_folders, crt_file)
            shutil.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
            ext_counter=ext_counter+1;
return ext_counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the directory path of the source in the destination:

```
source_file_path = os.path.join(root_path, crt_file)
dest_file_path   = os.path.join(dest_path, root_path ,crt_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But Your answer cause an error like: in copyfile
    raise SameFileError("{!r} and {!r} are the same file".format(src, dst))
shutil.SameFileError: '...' and '...' are the same file For addition both paths are in format like: C:\user\user_name\documents\...

Comment: If that helped or solved you issue consider to mark this answer as solved.